# MDM software on iPhone - Monitoring hotspot use?

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering, mobile-device-management

I have a company phone (iPhone 8) which I use as a hotspot for my personal phone sometime.

My company uses Blackberry MDM. In "rights", it says they can "list network information." What does that mean?

Can you they monitor my hotspot use (i.e. what I am using hotspot for? Websites visited, photos/messages sent etc.)?

I read somewhere that Apple does not allow monitoring of browsing details by MDMs - is this true? Does it apply to browsing when on a hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

"List Network Information" is related to blacklisted websites and what the device is using to connect to the internet (Roaming, VPN). For example if the corporate policy demands the device connecting through the corporate network.

Here you may get a sneak peak of what is able to get configured: http://www.wpci.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/BES10-2-FDM-EMM-data-sheet1.pdf (last page for iOS and Android)

Furthermore, see https://help.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-uem/12.7/administration/filtering-web-content.html and accompanied pages.

So, answering your question: It is possible, but you may never know what data your company is analyzing. The certificate with "list network information" just says it is theoretically possible.